# Is there a excel formula that can lookup the whole column K for any values that have more than 2 decimals?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to figure out if any of the values in Column K have more than 2 decimals?

So the formula I need would basically say TRUE if any of the values have more than 2 decimals or return the number of values that have more than 2 decimals or even better if it can even return the cell or row location(s)

[image]

I tried =IF(LEN(RIGHT(K2,LEN(K2)-FIND(".",K2)))>2,TRUE,FALSE) but it only gives me the results on a row-by-row basis. I also tried to do that by summing up the whole column but ended up getting some fake results.

Comment: I think this will be quite hard using formulas because of the base 10 vs base 2. Look at this image (comma is the decimalseparator in my Excel) https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTw8s.png There is clearly just two decimals, and removing the integer part should give us a length of 4, but we get 17. Perhaps it's possible with VBA using the `.Text` of the cell

Comment: it's a bit crude.. and still row-by-row basis.. but it works for all previous needed cases : `=IF((INT(K2*100)-K2*100)=0,"",CELL("address",K2))` | and I'll use Data > remove duplicate to "collect" the address as table. OR , use `=IF((INT(K2*100)-K2*100)=0,L3,SUBSTITUTE(CELL("address",K2),"$","")&","&L3)` to collect them as a list.

Comment: This seems like it might be an [x-y problem](https://xyproblem.info). Is this merely an exercise? Or is there a specific overlying problem you are trying to solve? Decimal numbers cannot always be expressed exactly in a binary system like Excel. Something like `=SUM(N(MOD(myRange*100,1)<>0))` will return the count of more than two decimal values.

Comment: If your values are in `A2:A6` then something like `=LET(rng,A2:A6,x,HSTACK(SEQUENCE(ROWS(rng)),rng),FILTER(x,INT(rng*100) <> (rng*100)))` will give you the indices of the required rows and their values (or `#CALC!` if there are no values with more than 2dp).

Comment: @DS_London What does the 2 relate to in CHOOSECOLS(x,2) ?

Comment: As Ron Rosenfeld mentioned you probably need it's row, because you need the strings/values of another column of the same row. Than Rons version can be used like so: `=FILTER(ResultRange,MOD(CheckRange*100,1)<>0))`

Comment: @IlyasEsa That was redundant, I realized, so I edited the comment. The CHOOSECOLS function lets you pick one or more columns out of a table.

Comment: Appreciate that formula but is there a way to just count how many times it occurs rather than the breakdown?

Comment: @IlyasEsa What do you not understand about my comment and answer? I thought I had answered that already.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I tried that but binary limitation are causing the issue and seems like there is no way around it

Comment: @IlyasEsa As I wrote, is this an `XY problem`? Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: So I have these multi currency files and where the currency is converted then it creates more than 2 decimals, I fix them with the ROUND formula but sometimes we still end up with more than 2 decimals for some values so it was to find out exactly how many value have more than 2 decimal values

Comment: @IlyasEsa And why do you need that information? What will you do with that?

Comment: Shouldn't you focus on fixing the formula you use to round then?

Comment: I kinda got it to work using this formula
=SUM(CHOOSECOLS(LET(rng,K2:K20,x,HSTACK(SEQUENCE(ROWS(rng)),rng),FILTER(x,INT(rng*100) <> (rng*100))),1)). It won't exactly tell me how many but if more than 0 then there could be a few with issues

Comment: @Illness Also, edit your question to provide sufficient information so we can reproduce your problem of your formula not rounding properly.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like it might be an [x-y problem](https://xyproblem.info).

- Is this merely an exercise? Or is there a specific overlying problem you are trying to solve?
- Note that decimal numbers cannot always be expressed exactly in a binary system like Excel.

Having written that, to get a count of values with more than two decimals try:

```
=SUM(N(MOD(myRange*100,1)<>0))
```

You don't write how you wish to return the addresses; the following will return the addresses as a vertical array (requires Excel 365):

```
=LET(
    a, ADDRESS(
        (MOD(myRange * 100, 1) <> 0) * ROW(myRange),
        COLUMN(myRange)
    ),
    FILTER(a, NOT(ISERROR(a)))
```